# Flutter Future.wait throws setState() or markNeedsBuild() exception

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I got this issue several times and I can fix that as wrap function with Futures or WidgetBindings.instance.addPostFrameCallback. But today I got a weird issue like this,

I have a some functions in some ChangeNotifierProviders:

```
Future<void> someFuncA()async{
isLoadingA = true;
notifyListeners();
//bla bla
}

Future<void> someFuncB()async{
isLoadingB = true;
notifyListeners();
//bla bla
}
```

I can call these in initState like this:

```
@override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
    
  Future.wait([       // This code throws setState() or markNeedsBuild()
       someFuncA(),
       someFuncB(),
    ]);
```

But when I change my function like this:

```
@override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
    
  Future.wait([                            // This code works without any error 
    Future.microtask(() => someFuncA()),
    Future.microtask(() => someFuncB()),
    ]);
```

In addition , this code works too

```
@override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
    
                        
    Future.microtask(()async{
       await someFuncA();
       await someFuncB();
    });
```

Ah , okey. Is there a something different between Future.wait and Future.microtask I dont know? Just I use Future.wait with parallel async futures for performance gain. Thank you.

Comment: When I use Future.wait for my functions I get Flutter  setState() or markNeedsBuild() exception , when I wrap my functions with Future.microtask like above code works. So what's wrong Future.wait? Is that work after build() method like Future.microtask too isn't it ?

Comment: initState cannot be async.  Even if you launch futures, they will happen after initState has finished.